# GMP Library: How to check first m-bit of a big integer

Tags: gmp

I'm using gmp (big integer library)

I have a value **b** I need to check whether first m-bit of it, is zero.

I know if I convert **b** to string I can do checking, but it's not efficient.

**Question 1:** I need to know whether the library has a function that returns first m-bit of a big integer.

---

To encode a big integer **c**, I convert it to string and then concatenate it with m zeros, e.g. imagine c in binary is 11, then I encode as: 1100000000

**Question 2**: I need to know whether I can do encoding faster using the library's function

Answer (score 1):

The GMP library provides plenty of bit manipulation primitives. Have a look at the [Logical and Bit Manipulation Functions](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Logic-and-Bit-Fiddling.html) chapter from the documentation.

For your first question, I think you want to use `mpz_tstbit`. For your second question, it sounds like you're trying to perform some bit shifting, which can be done via the [`mpz_mul_2exp`](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Arithmetic.html#Integer-Arithmetic) and the [`mpz_*_*_2exp`](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Division.html#Integer-Division) functions.